# How can I add 'System Language' as a language option in the settings of an Electron app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, macos, electron

I would like to add 'System Language' as a language option in the settings of an Electron app. I searched for keywords: 'language' and 'system language' through the [Electron documentation](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/all) but I could not find anything useful.

Where can I find documentation to help me understand how 'System Language' can be added as a language option in the settings of an Electron app?

Or, how can I add 'System Language' as a language option in the settings of an Electron app?

Answer (score 4):

You can use the browser's [`navigator.language`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NavigatorLanguage/language) API, which returns the user's preferred language according to the [BCP 47](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NavigatorLanguage/language) spec. Note that this API is only available in the renderer process, so you'll have to use IPC to call it from your main process if that's what you want.

```js
const lang = navigator.language;
console.log(lang); // e.g. "en-US", "fr", "es-ES", etc.
```

Answer (score 1):

Electron now has a [app.getLocale](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/main/docs/api/app.md#appgetlocale) function to get locale in main process